# I have an error when I build react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

Error build gradlew assembleRelease

Here is the error details:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':vision-camera-code-scanner:verifyReleaseResources'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':vision-camera-code-scanner:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
Required by:
project :vision-camera-code-scanner
project :vision-camera-code-scanner > project :react-native-vision-camera
project :vision-camera-code-scanner > project :react-native-vision-camera > project :react-native-reanimated
> Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Read timed out

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

My library versions:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.14.1",
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"
```

And I've also added this setting:

```
VisionCameraCodeScanner_targetSdkVersion = 31
VisionCameraCodeScanner_compileSdkVersion = 31
```

The previous few days it was running normally, but today an error occurred during build.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

https://jcenter.bintray.com is down currently. The service are not working.

jcenter is now phased out by j-labs.

Following example will help you.

1. React native version equal or greater than 0.66 will not have this issue.
2. Remove all J-Center dependencies.